# Delete old JetPack Site Stats? encrypted_search_terms in top search terms

Tags: statistics, plugin-jetpack, clone-site

I created a new baseball website. To create the site, I basically just duplicated my football site and changed/modified the theme.

Being that I simply copied a site, all of the JetPack Site Stats reference the old football site stats. So, top posts, top seaches, total views, busiest, etc. all refer to the football traffic. How can I delete these old stats, everything prior to March 26, 2012?

I should note that the old site used the Wordpress.com Site Stats plugin, but I updated to Jetpack after copying to the new site. I don't know if this makes a difference, but figured I should mention it.

Also, encrypted_search_terms shows in the dashboard widget for "Top Searches". I imagine this is from the old search and traffic results.

## UPDATE

I contacted the JetPack developers about this. Their reply:

> I can confirm that the two sites are establishing separate connections
> at this point, so your stats should be correctly reported moving
> forward. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to separate stats once
> they've already been combined.
>
> In the future, please be sure to set up databases and install
> WordPress for each instance separately.
>
> Feel free to drop us a line if we can be of any further assistance.

I then asked:

> Which table in the database controls the stats? So I can exclude it
> from export when I decide to copy the site again?

Their reply makes me believe that it is possible to remove old entries, but after multiple emails exchanged when I asked the initial question, they have not replied to my last question for three days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official developers:

"The site stats are maintained by wordpress.com, not your own site, therefore, there is no way to delete old stats"